# How to sort text/string in solr using a natural sort order?

Tags: sorting, solr, natural-sort

I would like to sort a list of values somewhat along the lines of:

> - 4
> - 5xa
> - 8kdjfew454
> - 9
> - 10
> - 999cc
> - b
> - c9
> - c10cc
> - c11

In other words, what is sometimes referred to as "natural sorting", where text is sorted alphabetically/lexicographically where there is text, but numerically where there are numbers, even if both are mixed in the same string.

I can't find anyway to do this in Solr (4.0 atm). Is there standard way to do this or at least a workable "recipe" ?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you can achieve is described in [this article](http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Make-numbers-behave-when-sorting-alphanumerically-in-Solr.aspx)

**From the article:**

> To force numbers to sort numerically, we need to left-pad any numbers
> with zeroes: 2 becomes 0002, 10 becomes 0010, 100 becomes 0100, et
> cetera. Then even a lexical sort will arrange values like this:
>
> Title No. 1 Title No. 2 Title No. 10 Title No. 100
>
> **The Field Type**
>
> This alphanumeric sort field type converts any numbers found to 6
> digits, padded with zeroes. (If you expect numbers larger than 6
> digits in your field values, you will need to increase the number of
> zeroes when padding.)
>
> The field type also removes English and French leading articles,
> lowercases, and purges any character that isn’t alphanumeric. It is
> English-centric, and assumes that diacritics have been folded into
> ASCII characters.

```html
<fieldType name="alphaNumericSort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="false" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
         input string is preserved as a single token
      -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
         when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
      -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
    <!-- Remove leading articles -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="^(a |the |les |la |le |l'|de la |du |des )" replacement="" replace="all"
    />
    <!-- Left-pad numbers with zeroes -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="(\d+)" replacement="00000$1" replace="all"
    />
    <!-- Left-trim zeroes to produce 6 digit numbers -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="0*([0-9]{6,})" replacement="$1" replace="all"
    />
    <!-- Remove all but alphanumeric characters -->
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^a-z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"
    />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

> **Sample output**
>
> Title No. 1 => titleno000001
> Title No. 2 => titleno000002
> Title No. 10 => titleno000010
> Title No. 100 => titleno000100